# Wrong menuitem found when fragment changes in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following menu in the main fragment that contains a list:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item
      app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
      android:id="@+id/menu_item_search"
      app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
      android:title="Search"
      android:iconifiedByDefault="true"/>
</menu>
```

It has the necessary setting in the onCreate:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Its `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) ((MenuBuilder)menu).getActionItems().get(0).getActionView();
    if(searchView!=null)
    {
      searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
      searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
      searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }
```

When I click an item, a new fragment opens and it has a different menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">
  <item android:id="@+id/action_Save"
        android:title="@string/action_Save"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        />
</menu>
```

Its `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_second, menu);
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
```

If I press Back:

```
  if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

my first fragment opens and tries to find its SearchView.

It can't find it as *the menu of the second fragment* is checked and it finds only the ***Save*** item.

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: does the second fragment remove the search menu item?

Comment: It does not but in both case only 1 menuitem is found, as the Acitivity has no menu at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [invalidateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) to reset your menu for the fragment.

Comment: I added `invalidateOptionsMenu() ` to `onBackPressed` but it does not work.

Comment: hope you have setHasOptionsMenu(true); and the necessary menu item loading code in both the fragments.

Comment: You can read them all above. I set everything yet it doesn't work. The first fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu is called but it seems to ignore the inflation and takes the previous menu.

Comment: can you try adding addOnBackStackChangedListener() and call invalidateOptionsMenu() from there ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change how the menuitem was found.

Instead of this:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) ((MenuBuilder)menu).getActionItems().get(0).getActionView();
```

I use now this:

```
 SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search).getActionView();
```

This way it works.